# A simple maths Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, pattern

Someone asked me this today.

> If
>
> 4 + 6 = 60,
> 4 + 8 = 61,
> 7 + 8 = 62,
> 11 + 12 = ?

I'm unable to find the logic here. Can you guys solve this?

Comment: Btw, I am told that the answer is 61.

Comment: Nup that's wrong, Obviously the answer is 63. It's a simple sequence, independent of the LHS.

Comment: I thought exactly the same. But the reasoning is different here I guess.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I think answer is

> 61
>
>  **Logic :** The numbers on the left are months of the year and answer is total days in those months.

Answer (score 4):

> why not 72?
>
> (4 + 6) * 6 + 0 = 60
>
> (4 + 8) * 5 + 1 = 61
>
> (7 + 8) * 4 + 2 = 62
>
> (11 + 12) * 3 + 3 = 72

Comment: Nice idea, but it doesn't explain why the numbers in the LHS are what they are.

Comment: yes you are right :)

Answer (score -4):

```
4+6=60
4+8=61
+3
7+8=62
+4-+4
11+12= 23X3=69
```

Answer = 69

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE . Could you elaborate on your answer ? Right now I fail to grasp the logic behind those calculations...